# Theorem-like environment with optional title

Tags: spacing, environments, theorems, amsthm

I'm using the `amsthm` packages for theorems. I would like to define an environment `paragraph` which should resemble the look of a theorem environment (definition theoremstyle), but it shouldn't say **1.1 Paragraph.**. Instead of **Paragraph** it should say nothing, or the content of an optional argument. Let me illustrate what I mean:

```
\begin{definition}
Lorem.
\end{definition}

\begin{paragraph}
Ipsum.
\end{paragraph}

\begin{paragraph}[Optional Title]
Dolor.
\end{paragraph}
```

This should produce output as follows:

**1.1 Definition.** Lorem.

**1.2.** Ipsum

**1.3 Optional Title.** Dolor.

Getting this done roughly isn't too difficult, but I would like to get it as close to the original theorem environments as possible. So the spacing after **1.2.** should be exactly the same as the spacing after **1.1 Definition.**, and similarly for the space above and below the environments and whatever else subtle things are handled by `amsthm`, which I might not even recognize. How can this be done?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The command `\paragraph` is defined by most document classes. It's thus not a good idea to define a theorem-like environment called `paragraph`. Please do tell us how to you try to define the `paragraph` environment at present, as well as which document class you employ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to define your own theorem styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{swapdef}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\upshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {\thmnumber{#2} \thmname{#1}\thmnote{ (#3)}} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\newtheoremstyle{para}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\upshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {\thmnumber{#2}\@ifnotempty{#3}{ \thmnote{#3}}} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{swapdef}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\theoremstyle{para}
\newtheorem{para}[definition]{}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{definition}
Lorem.
\end{definition}

\begin{para}
Ipsum.
\end{para}

\begin{para}[Optional Title]
Dolor.
\end{para}

\begin{definition}[Name]
Lorem.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]