# Unwanted horizontal space with Cref command from cleveref and amsthm

Tags: cleveref, amsthm, white-space

I have a problem with the presence of an unwanted space when I use amsthm and cleveref.

The following is a MWE that highlights the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor={red}}

\newtheoremstyle{test}{}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}{#1#2 (\thmnote{#3})}
\theoremstyle{test}
\newtheorem{test}{Test T}

\begin{document}

\begin{test}[Test Name]
\label{test}
Test.
\end{test}

\Cref{test}.

\end{document}
```

As it can be noticed, where I would like to obtain with Cref "Test T1", I actually get "Test T 1".

Any feedback will be most welcome!

Comment: shouldn't the T be part of the counter format not the environment name?, you currently get a space for the same reason you would get **Theorem 1** not  **Theorem1**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the immediate reply! I see. However, my problem is that I would like to use that newtheoremstyle with various newtheorem, so to speak, all with different letters (e.g., S, T, etc), but sharing the same newtheoremstyle, without being forced to define a new one for every letter (if possible at all).

Comment: well I don't really know cleveref that well to be honest  I answered with the classic latex view that the counter would be T1 here (or at least  I think that's the classic view) but feel free not to accept, someone knowing more cleveref tricks may give a different answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newtheoremstyle{test}{}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}{#1 #2 (\thmnote{#3})}
\theoremstyle{test}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}
\renewcommand\thetest{T\arabic{test}}
\crefname{test}{Test}{Tests} % for \cref and \Cref calls with more than 1 arg.

\begin{document}

\begin{test}[Test Name] \label{testa} Test. \end{test}
\begin{test}[Another Test] \label{testb} Another test. \end{test}

\Cref{testa}.

\Cref{testa,testb}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, anyway: much appreciated! :)

Comment: +1. I think it would be useful to run `\crefname{test}{Test}{Tests}` immediately after `\renewcommand\thetest{T\arabic{test}}`, in order to enable the sucessful execution of an instruction of the form `\cref{testa,testb}`.

Comment: @Mico er if you say so, I have never actually used cref apart from the occasional answer here, can you edit  this answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the feedbacks: I was implementing the – brilliant – answer!

Comment: Happy to oblige. :-)

Comment: @Mico thanks...

Comment: I have a – most probably – silly question. I am trying to implement @egreg answer from this question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/613866/theorem-like-environment-with-optional-title) to polish the MWE and get rid of the round brackets when there is no name in the test, but it doesn't work and I get something along the following lines "T1ifnotempty [...etc]". How can this be fixed?

Comment: @Kolmin probably you have not used `\makeatletter` so `\@ifnotempty` parsed as `\@ ifnotempty` and typesets `ifnotempty`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot: much (much) appreciated!